# How to add a wordpress blog in node express existing website?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express

I build a website in node express. But now I just need to add a WordPress blog. How do I install WordPress in my project and integrate the blog page in the existing website?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways,

1. Install WordPress in sub-domain of your NodeJs App i.e. blog.domain.tld
2. Another way, you can install WordPress any path [before that you need to install PHP and MySQL (You can use RDS if you are on AWS)], then use WordPress REST API to get post content and display in your NodeJs-Express Apps

More info about WordPress Rest API [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)